# Removing fields in an exported table using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, attribute-table, fields-attributes, export, python-script-tool

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.6: ArcMap 10.6. ArcPy script within a custom toolbox.

At the end of my script, I want to export the attribute table of a File Geodatabase Feature Class into a .csv file, however, I would like to only have specific fields within the attribute table to be exported into the .csv file.

I am getting the table to export, though, all the fields in the attribute table still remain and the one's meant to be removed are still there.

My only thought as to why this may not be working is because I am using a File Geodatabase Feature Class.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't look like you're specifying the output fields in your `arcpy.TableToTable_conversion()` line. I see you have 3 parameters for it, none of which call to the previous lines you have been working on.

Take a read through the Table to Table [docs](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/tools/conversion-toolbox/table-to-table.htm), specifically looking at the field mapping. This suggests you need to call the field mapping parameters at this part of the command (so the 5th parameter).

To understand field mapping, you can read the [docs](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/analyze/arcpy-classes/fieldmappings.htm) about these too.

EDIT:
Try this code and see if it works for you. I've tested on my own file and it works fine. I couldn't figure out a way to tidy it into loops as the `FieldMap()` object seems to only be allowed one value.

EDIT 2: Added some pandas lines to remove the OID column after creation of the csv (the first column). This needs to create another csv, so the original one is renamed as a temp file, then deleted at the end of the process.

```py
#Modules
import arcpy
import pandas as pd
import os

#Workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\Your_Location\\Store.gdb"

#Variables
inFile = "sampevents"
outLoc = "C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop"

#Define field mapping objects
#fm1, fm2, fm3, fm4 and fm5 are all part of fms
fm1 = arcpy.FieldMap()
fm2 = arcpy.FieldMap()
fm3 = arcpy.FieldMap()
fm4 = arcpy.FieldMap()
fm5 = arcpy.FieldMap()

fms = arcpy.FieldMappings()

#Fields to keep
#adding the fields to their individual field maps
fm1.addInputField(inFile, "Name")
fm2.addInputField(inFile, "Size")
fm3.addInputField(inFile, "Height")
fm4.addInputField(inFile, "Type")
fm5.addInputField(inFile, "Condition")

#Complete the field map
#adding the components above into the final mapping (fms)   
fms.addFieldMap(fm1)
fms.addFieldMap(fm2)
fms.addFieldMap(fm3)
fms.addFieldMap(fm4)
fms.addFieldMap(fm5)

#Perform the function
arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(inFile, outLoc, "Temp_Export.csv","",fms)

#Open the temp file
df = pd.read_csv(outLoc + "\\Temp_Export.csv")

#Set the first column as a variable
first_column = df.columns[0]

#Delete the first column and export to your end file
df = df.drop([first_column], axis=1)
df.to_csv(outLoc + "\\Sample_Events_Table.csv", index=False)

#Delete the temp csv
os.remove(outLoc + "\\Temp_Export.csv")
os.remove(outLoc + "\\Temp_Export.txt")
```

Comment: Edited answer to include some code to try

Comment: Super. I couldn't find an inline way to do it, but I did find a solution elsewhere on the web which I've combined in. It now first creates a temporary csv (name how you want), then removes the OID column and exports to a new csv. It then deletes the temporary csv to clean up. Should work. Please accept the answer if you are happy so others can see the solution works clearly :)